# Reloading jqGrid with filter text, modifies the original datasource, after reloadGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that initially displays 100 records. After typing a search text, it gets filtered into, say 26. I select one of those 26 rows and edit the fields using a modal dialog. After refreshing the grid as like below,

```
function refreshGrid() {
    $('#grid_id').jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json', url: 'URL' });
    $("#grid_id").trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

The grid retains the search text and the 26 records were refreshed fine (as expected).

But the actual problem comes next is, when I clear or edit the search text, filtering happens among the 26 records only (the original datasource with 100 records is cropped). Only after a complete page reload, the jqgrid gets the original datasource.

How can we retain the search text and make the grid to filter the original datasource while editing the search text, after reload?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How do you clear the text? If you clear the text this does not mean that the search parameters are cleared. It is not know which search methods you are using. I'm not sure that I correctly understand the question - it is something confusing to me.

Comment: @TonyTomov "How do you clear the text" //When you type into the filter textbox, the grid records will be filtered as per the text you type right? I am reloading a jqgrid along with such filter text, but after reloading if I manually alter or delete the filter text, I get lesser number of records than expected.

Comment: Do you use toolbarFilter or dialog search or single common search?

Comment: @TonyTomov toolbarFilter

Answer (score 0):

To clear the toolbar search manually and reload the grid  you will need to call the method clearToolbar with true parameter like this

```
var sgrid = $("#grid_id")[0];
sgrid.clearToolbar( true );
```

Please consult the [docs here](https://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#other-toolbar-methods) and how the method is called.

To refresh with the new values use method refreshFilterToolbar